# Office UI Fabric Panel scrolling to first input

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I have a problem with Office UI Fabric's Panel (well, also Modal). I'm rendering them with multiple input fields to provide data for my app. Due to the number of fields the controls are rendered with a scroll bar. After scrolling down and clicking outside of the input, the focus is being set on the first textfield/dropdown in the container panel what causes the whole thing to be scrolled to the top. Is there a way to prevent setting the focus/scrolling to the first element when clicking outside of the input?

Comment: can you show your code on  #codpen or #jsffiddle or give some code which you try...

Comment: Just confirming that I also have this issue.

Comment: I opened issue here with code reproducing issue and video:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/3804

Comment: Great to hear that Matt, thanks! Was busy with other stuff and forgot about the issue. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a bug and has been resolved already. Tested it in the version 5.56.0.